# Is it possible to see activity statistics on Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-network, left-4-dead-2, left-4-dead

I'm debating between the original L4D and L4D2.  I like the original better, but I'm worried that I'm going to discover that there aren't any/many games.

Is there a way I can see how many people are playing a given Xbox Live game at a given time, or in a given time period?  Specifically, I want to do this WITHOUT owning the game and I also want to know if there are people within reasonable ping distance of me.

Comment: while this question would be nice to know an answer to, as it stands it's only relevant to someone *right now*, so is too localized in time.  I'd suggest revising it to something more general and to the effect of "How can I see how many people play L4D on XBL" or "How do I know if a XBL game community is still active", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Xbox Live doesn't provide any overall stats publicly that I've ever seen for game activity as it's happening. They provide sometimes weekly or monthly stats on Majorn Nelson's blog, but it's only Top 20 activity. [In this example from April 11th](http://majornelson.com/2011/04/20/live-activity-for-week-of-april-11/), Left 4 Dead 2 is #20 in activity, but they don't provide overall numbers of number of players or anything what you are looking for.

I am not sure if Left 4 Dead 2 even provides in-game numbers for number of people playing currently, but I do know games like the Halo series, the Call of Duty series and others will show you how many active players are in the different multiplayer games at a given time. Your best bet would likely be to hit up some forums of Left 4 Dead players and see if they could give you activity numbers if they're even available.